# How can I extract a leaf from this image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-manipulation, computer-vision

I have a botanical tree with some leaves. I want to extract the leaf A. However, leaf A stays on top of leaf B so that I could not find any method to tract the leaf A. Is there any suggestion?
Thank you very much[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a hard problem but still doable. I have not worked on this but what I can suggest at the moment is that you can use gabor filters to create a feature for that specific leaf. Once you know the feature vector, you can then extract other leaves using that filter. Remember that you will need a collection of filters not just one filter in order to nail the problem. Each filter will have its specific behaviour against which you will decide what beviour represents a leaf. This means you convolve a gabor filter with the image in small windows to find the right behaviour at the leaf. Hope this helps.